# SMART SVN connection time out on large update

Tags: svn

I am new to Mac and Smart SVN, I checked out a large project (15 GB approx.) file, which took several minutes, but later the check out stopped in between, showing a `connection timed out` alert. Now I don't know how to move forward.

Comment: What's the client and the server's version?